# PHP For() Loop Issue

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

[image]
[image]

I have a question that I have been stuck on for several hours now.  I have played around with numerous types of for() and while() loops.  I put them in different locations with different variables and ran different things, nothing worked..

**My question:**

Why is my program giving all users below the first one the same level?  You can clearly see in the picture that Nicolas has much more XP.  (5,000 xp is level 20, and if "Nic5" was first in the database then it would change the "Skill Level" to 20.

I know that the returned variable `$lvl` isn't changing for each player that loads and this is why each player is getting the first player's level.

Can anybody help me with this please?

**Notes:**
*`0` = a column that holds experience for a players skill level.*

**class calculatelevel**:

```
class calculatelevel {

function level($skillnum)
{

$host = "*";
$user = "*";
$pass = "*";
$db = "*";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die($con->error);
$res = $con->query("SELECT `0` FROM hiscores");

$max = 99;

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $xp = $row['0'];

    // Find the appropriate level
    for ($lvl = 1; $lvl < $max; $lvl++) //this for loop runs 99 times
    {
        if ($xp < $this->experience($lvl))//if players xp in skill is less than experience(level 1-99)
        {
            // Level found
            $lvl -= 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
        return $lvl;
}

public function experience($lvl)
{
    $xp = 0;
    for($x = 1; $x < $lvl; $x++)
    {
        $xp += floor($x + 300 * pow(2, ($x / 7)));
    }
    return floor($xp / 4);
}
}
```

**Method that writes database information to page.**

```
if($res->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table>
     <tr>
        <td>Rank</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Skill Level</td>
        <td>Total Exp</td>         </tr>";

while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo 'ran';
    $calc = new calculatelevel(); 
    $level = $calc->level(0);

     echo '<tr>
        <td>'.($count+1).'</td>
        <td>'. htmlspecialchars($row['username']) .'</td>
        <td>'.number_format($level).'</td>
        <td>'.number_format($row['0']).'</td>
        </tr>';
     $count++;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with this:"SELECT `0` FROM hiscores" - having a field called `0` seems to me to be asking for trouble.

Comment: 0 = a table that holds experience for a players skill level.

Comment: The 0 is unimportant but yes, elune is correct.

Comment: Really need some help, somebody..

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop and for loop are structured incorrectly.  You are looking at only the first row and returning the level for that row every time.  You `break` the for loop when you find the level for that row's player, then immediately return that level.  Result: it looks like everyone has the same level.

**EDIT:** Okay, here are a few more thoughts.

First, a column named `0` is asking for trouble, as Mike W pointed out.  You say `0` is a table, but if that's the case, your `SELECT` statement doesn't make sense.  The first thing I would try is changing the column name to something that isn't a number, like `xp`.

Second, you really should make only one database connection and use it throughout the entire request, if possible.  Opening a new connection each time a particular function runs will tie up a server quickly.

Third, the obvious problem in your current code is this:

function level($skillnum) {

```
    // other code here....

    // Okay, you load a row's data into $row, with the idea that you will repeat this.
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        // $xp is set to the experience points for the user you just loaded
        $xp = $row['0'];

        // You now look at each level, starting at 1, to see if the 
        // user's xp is greater than the cutoff for that level
        for ($lvl = 1; $lvl < $max; $lvl++) //this for loop runs 99 times
        {
            // If the user's xp is less than the cutoff...
            if ($xp < $this->experience($lvl))//if players xp in skill is less than experience(level 1-99)
            {
                // ... then you go back down one level...
                // Level found
                $lvl -= 1;
                // ... and quit the for loop!
                break;
            }
        }
        // okay, you're out of the for loop, so you go back to the while loop...
        // a new row is loaded...
        // and $xp and $lvl are both overwritten with that user's values
    }

    // So, the while loop has run once for each player...
    // ... but you are only returning one player's level!
    return $lvl;
}
```

Also, you have defined `calculatelevel::level` to require a parameter `$skillnum`, but you never use it in the code posted here.

I suspect there is another glitch in your real code causing it to return the first player's level, rather than the last player's level.  It could be a problem with the `0` column name; that *really* should change.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a more specific fix?  As I said I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: 0 is a column, not a table.  I made a typo.              I replaced the break; with return $lvl; in hopes that instead of returning the last column it would return $lvl containing the players XP for the column it's on.  Once it returns the $lvl I need to stop the while loop and write that user to the page. Then I need to continue the while loop where it left off.  I believe that is what I have to do, how do I do it? Also, the level function takes a parameter because eventually it will be able to be ran for what ever skill it is given.  However, for right now I am only testing one skill.

Comment: Replacing the `break` with `return $lvl;` will get you the same problem, just a different way; it will return the first player's level only.  You need a different logical structure -- `return` is the wrong way to go about this.  Instead, either call the method once per player or store an array of players' levels.  Any way you try to do it with `return`ing a single $lvl value based on a query of all players, you will still have your problem.

Comment: I have used most of your suggested fixes, including the idea of my own to completely re-write it.  It seems to be fetching the xp from the database but it isn't calculating it correctly, some how.  The users are posted to the page, however their levels are 1, 1, instead of 99, 99.  XP is still the same.  Here is my updated code, is any of the syntax wrong now?: http://pastebin.com/Vv10h5Hq

Comment: Before you do anything else, change that ``0`` column name; that is really asking for problems.  Then, you really should sit down with a pencil and paper and map out how you want your logic to flow -- your existing code is simply structured incorrectly to return a different value for each user.

Comment: What I am lacking is enough knowledge in PHP.  I will map out what I want my code to do, however, can you explain to me this:  How do I fetch data  row by row for the amount of rows in the table?  Will putting my code that prints out the data in a method and then calling it fix this?

Comment: You need to use [WHERE and LIMIT clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).  The problem in your code is not the PHP; it is the underlying logic of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you :)  I will look into WHERE and LIMIT.